# android studio problem call method from another class

Tags: java, android-studio

it successfully run this application but after i clicked on button it pop-up error. can anyone explain to me why get error?

first class

```
public class Storepage extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newpage);


    }

public void hello()
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Second class

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colour1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Storepage wow = new Storepage();
                wow.hello();


            }
        });


    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NVIZ.png)

2019-12-27 14:18:39.278 20488-20488/com.example.sharedpreferences E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sharedpreferences, PID: 20488
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
        at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:130)
        at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:5688)
        at com.example.sharedpreferences.Storepage.hello(Storepage.java:21)
        at com.example.sharedpreferences.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

above is the display error

Comment: Can you post the error stacktrace?

Comment: i posted alrdy.

Answer (score 0):

You can not initialize Activity class like you did

```
Storepage wow = new Storepage();//Wrong
 wow.hello();
```

That is wrong. Either put hello() method inside separate class and call like this below.

```
public class ActivityRouter{

public static void hello()
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

and call like below on button click .

```
ActivityRouter.hello();
```